# Neo4j not enough memory for CREATE query - try increasing ‘dbms.memory.heap.max_size’ exception

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a problem with scalability of my Neo4j query.
I am trying to populate a database with these queries:

```
CREATE (Visitor1: Visitor {MAC:'00:0a:95:9d:68:16'})
CREATE (Visitor2: Visitor {MAC:'a7:e1:29:0f:7b:42'})
…

CREATE (CheckPoint1: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 1})
CREATE (CheckPoint2: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: 2})
…

CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit1: Visit {EnterTime: 1491061320000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit2: Visit {EnterTime: 1491061860000})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint46)
…
```

These queries are generated by a script I have written. The database is successfully created for 10 visitors and 100 visitors. But when I am trying to create 1000 visitors (50 checkpoints and about 6000 visits), the database throws and exception:

```
There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing ‘dbms.memory.heap.max_size’ in neo4j configuration.
```

I think the problem is with my query. Any ideas how to improve it?

I will be very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to use parameters in query. Do not know how you load your data, but a general example would look like this.

```
MERGE (Visitor1: Visitor {MAC:params.mac})
MERGE (CheckPoint1: CheckPoint {CheckPointId: params.checkpoint})
CREATE  (Visitor1)-[:MAKES]->(Visit2: Visit {EnterTime: params.enterTime})-[:TO]->(CheckPoint1)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into this!